# Use request module to download and get urls in mobile application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, node-request

I made a small script that use `request`:

```
request({
  url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json&max-results=1&q=" + encodeURIComponent(trackName),
  json: true
}, function (dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents, data) {
});
```

and now I want to port it to android using Ionic Framework. **Is it possible to get and download easily urls?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic is built on angular so you can use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) method to request remote data.

```
$http({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos',
    params: {
      alt: 'json',
      max-results: 1,
      q: trackName
    }
  })
  .success(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
    console.log('error');
  });
```